# Validate URL with regex issue with parenthesis and the caret

Tags: php, regex

For starters I have checked out a couple of the other regex threads and this is not the constantly asked 'how do I validate URLs using Regex' question.

I am checking to see if the referring URL is either http or https and also that the 'subdomain' consists of either 'staging', 'www', or 'search'.

```
^(https|http)://(staging|www|search).mysite.com
```

(this problem has been solved, new question after edit) I believe the issue I am having involves the parenthesis adjacent to the opening caret.

Any ideas?

Also how would I go about allowing anything after the .com part?  And for some reason I can characters in front of the URL for instance 2http://staging.mysite.com will still work, why is this?

edit: I guess my browser might have cached the original regex script because the original issue is now fixed.

Now my only questions is how do I make sure 2http://staging.mysite.com will not validate? I thought the caret means the string has to start with http or https.

I am doing a preg_match and I guess it's just checking to see if the string contains the requirements above but is not checking to see if it actually starts with the http or https

Comment: what is the error? the parentheses are fine. (and your dot is matching everything but no big deal). Try escaping the forward slashes, too. '\/'

Comment: @sweaver2112 For some reason the string will validate in preg_match even if the URL doesn't actually start with http or https.  That is to say I can add whatever before the http and as long as the rest of the URL is in tact the preg match and regex will pass as being correct even though it is not.

Comment: add the beginning of the string to your pattern as shown below: `^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "https://www.mysite.com/foo/bar";

preg_match("~^(https|http)://(staging|www|search)\.mysite.com~", $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

array
  0 => string 'https://www.mysite.com' (length=22)
  1 => string 'https' (length=5)
  2 => string 'www' (length=3)
```

works like a charm. if you don't demand an end to the pattern (using `$`), there can be arbitrary characters following. 2http:// won't work because we required the string to begin with (https|http) using `^`.

Comment: You've got it thank you very much good sir! I'm going to have to look up why the regex begins and ends with a ~ but thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: thats arbitrary. you can use slashes if you like. if you do, you will have to escape the slashes in your pattern: `preg_match("/^(https|http):\/\/(staging|www|search)\.mysite.com/", $string, $matches);`